# Number of new lines in a string as integer

Tags: text-processing, grep, string, echo

I want to find the number of new lines in a string and then use this number in a `while` loop as the limit.

I can find and write the number of lines using:

```
echo "$MY_STRING" | grep -c '$'
```

In order to have the number of lines as integer and use it in while loop I do this:

```
MYNUM="$MY_PEERS" | grep -c '$'
```

However, this line writes 0, which is not the number of lines in my string, immediately to the terminal. Moreover, I cannot use `MYNUM` in a `while` loop. (I use `$MYNUM` in the `while`) How can I obtain number of lines so that I can use it in a `while` loop as the limit?

Comment: I think your use of `echo` is the issue here, use `echo -e` to allow interpretation of `\n` in the string.. or use `printf` as echo adds a `\n` on its own, or perhaps `echo -ne` will work... also, `wc -l` would be an alternate to `grep -c '$'`

Comment: Note the number of _lines_ (`grep -c (all)`) is not the number of _newline characters_ (`wc -l`) if the last line is unterminated, although most 'good' data doesn't use an unterminated last line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I don't fully understand *why* you need this, this is one way that you can get it done.  The key is the `$( )` to capture the output and assign it to a variable.

**Code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
IFS='' read -r -d '' TEST_STR <<-'EOF'
    Test text
    quick brown fox
    lazy dog
EOF

NEW_LINE_COUNT=$(echo "$TEST_STR" | wc -l)

echo "$TEST_STR"
echo "$NEW_LINE_COUNT"
```

**Results:**

```
Test text
quick brown fox
lazy dog

4
```

Comment: Great! Thank you! It works as I want it. For my project I create number of P2P stations. When a station discovers other stations the results return as a string each line having one device. Then, I need to check the properties of each single discovered device. I plan doing this in a while loop. This is why I needed this information. I am a new guy for Linux shell, so I don't even know very basic operations. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to count lines in your multiline string to look at the individual devices. The `for` loop in tandem with array variables can be put to use here like as:

```
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a Multi_Line_Str <<STR
    $(printf '%s\n' 'device_'{A..E})
STR

for device in "${Multi_Line_Str[@]}"
do
    echo "<$device>"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a multi-line string, you may simply use `wc -l` to count the number of lines in it:

```
printf '%s' "$string" | wc -l
```

To store that number in a variable:

```
nlines=$( printf '%s' "$string" | wc -l )
```

However, you don't need this number for doing a while loop:

```
printf '%s' "$string" |
while read -r line; do
   # do something with "$line"
done
```

Depending on what you're doing with each line, you may not need a while loop at all:

```
printf '%s' "$string" | awk '<some awk script>'
```

Depending on how the data is generated, you may not even have to store it in a multi-line variable at all:

```
some_command | some_line_by_line_processing
```

Here, `some_command` may be a while loop, a collection of commands in a subshell (`(...)`) or a simple command that generates output and `some_line_by_line_processing` may likewise be a simple command (like `awk`) or a loop or whatever other thing you need to process the output of the first part of the pipeline line by line.

Comment: Thank you for your command! 3rd part of your answer seems to be what I want to do. Here's the specific direction for what I want to do. I have a string that consists of MAC addresses of devices, say `echo "$MY_PEERS" yields `00:00:00:00:00:01
00:00:00:00:00:02`